# how do i check if the current time is exactly i.e. 12:03 PM

Tags: c#

I need to check if the current time is exactly 12:03 PM to perform some task.

This is how i am trying to achieve it.

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("12:03"); 
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if (start == now)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

**Problem:**
`Start` set to `{12:03:00}`

But `Now` set to  `{12:03:01.8493604}` with additional information.

How i can do this comparison?
Any idea

Comment: Try this :            DateTime dtNow =  DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan now = new TimeSpan(dtNow.Hour, dtNow.Minute, dtNow.Second);

Comment: You need to be more clear about your requirements. Taking your question literally, the only possible answer is "you can't". The chances of your code executing the `Now` property getter _exactly_ at 12:03 pm, right on the dot, is basically nil.

Comment: The most practical approach is to compute the `TimeSpan` between now and 12:03 pm, and invoke a delay (e.g. `Task.Delay()`) for that length of time, and execute whatever you want to execute then, regardless of when you see the timer expire. The answer to _that_ question is found in the many existing duplicates. If you want something else, you need to explain it better.

Comment: It's unlikely it will ever be exactly 12:03. Try checking for greater than and equal to, or compare just the hours and the minutes.

Comment: Wonder why i am getting negative. I hit some point that c# cant do and i wasnt aware about it.

Comment: other way. You can use timer with `Interval = 60000` then `string DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"); if (DateTimeNow == "12:03"){return true;} else {return false;}` . Make sure the Interval is 1min else the timer hits and return true between time - 12:03 - 12:04

Comment: Ok, thanks all, i got the point. i was doing something really wrong by exact at 12:03. The ideal thing is any time betyween 12:00 PM to 1:00 PM.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact("12:03", "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"), "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var n = DateTime.Compare(start, end);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if (n == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can subtract `TimeSpans` which gives you the difference between two DateTimes (or TimeSpans for that matter). Once you have the difference you can use the [`TotalSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) (or one of the other similar named properties, like TotalHours, TotalDays) to base any logic on that time window.

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("15:09"); 
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

Action<object> action = (s) => { Console.WriteLine(s); }; // what needs to be executed

// a 'negative' timespan means we're not there yet
TimeSpan diff = now - start;
// within the minute
if (diff.TotalSeconds > -1 && diff.TotalSeconds < 60) {
   action("awesome"); // execute
} 
else
{
    // if we are to early...
    if (diff.TotalSeconds<0) 
    {
        // ... schedule the work with a timer
        // waiting for the difference in the diff TimeSpan to pass
        new System.Threading.Timer((state) => action(state), // execute
            "FooBar",  // state
            diff.Duration(),  // how long to wait for the abolsute Duration 
            new TimeSpan(-1));  // no repeat
    }
    else
    {
        // we are late ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that when your logic is invoked from a Timer the code runs on a different thread. Make sure your code can handle that, specially with shared state and/or UI interactions.